# What is the source of noise in this AD620/OP490 EEG circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise

I figured out the major source of the noises, it's from the ac wire a meter away!

For weeks I kept adjusting the HC11 program to try to fix the waveforms to recover the original bricked firmware. I adjusted the delay time to different values in the subroutine where the ADC was activated (for example LDX #$1500 vs #$750) and every time different waveforms showed up like (this was even when no electrode wires were connected).

[image]

[image]

The third example of different waveform is in the image below in the original message.

I couldn't figure out at start where the different large amplitude waveforms were coming from. Then last night after trying it out for hours, out of desperation, I pulled the ac plug, and suddenly the waveforms got normal (at least the large distortions disappeared (see halfway in the images for comparisons))!

In the above two waveforms. The initial one can give the impression it's AC 60 hz sine waves. But in the second waveform. It's like there are standing waves. What do you call the phenomenon? is it harmonic distortion? What is the proper term(s) for it?

Do you think ac interference comes from the AD620, the OP490 or the HC11 ADC circuits??

Using a gaussmeter. I figured the circuit can respond to electromagnetic field down to 1 milligauss.

By the way.. someone said I should put capacitor in the unused input pins of the op-amps. How about the unused input pins of the HC11 ADC (there are 8 inputs, should I put capacitors to the 6 unused too?)

Previous message:

The circuit diagram came from the Brainmaster 2E EEG above. Their latest software I downloaded in their website bricked the EEPROM memory. Their Support refused to give me the firmware or fix and said I must buy the new $2000 model, but I don't want to just throw this away. I managed to program the built-in 68HC11 with simple commands to read from the ADC and output it to the serial port via serial to ide adaptor in Virtualbox. However, the output I'm getting in channel 1 has many high frequency noises (see picture below.. where is the high frequency coming from?). The top is the raw waveform. I'm trying to add program for boxcar filtering but I need to know first what you think of the EEG circuit itself.

[image]

See the full circuit diagram below first. The power supply uses battery with an LM78L05 transistor to maintain 5 volts.  Is it a common combination of AD620 and OP490 you saw before? In the Ref pin 5 of AD620. It is connected to the output of the OP490 but also connected to -IN A (pin 2) of the same OP490 via a resistor in series. Then it has a capacitor in between "Out A" and -In A of the Op490. Is this feedback commonly done? The ref of the EEG electrode is connected to both +IN of the AD620 and +IN A of the Op490.

original message

The following is the complete circuit with channel 2 connected to the HC11. I thought I can just show channel 1. All inputs are connected. I'm programming the HC11 for noise reduction after learning how to enable the ADC and display it at the port.

[image]

[image]

I'm analyzing an EEG circuit (where the input is microvolts and the circuit is amplifying it to volts level,) in order to understand why there is high frequency noise on the output (this is before the ADC/microcontroller which I'm learning to program.)

Normally, what components are the sources of noise in the above analog part?

Also, can someone simulate this with Spice to see what the outputs are for any test microvolt-level inputs? I don't have Spice and don't know how to use it.

Comment: How are you powering the circuit?

Comment: [LTspice is free.](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html)  It is a useful tool to have and use.  Download it and see if you can get it to simulate your circuit.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your circuit is missing [decoupling capacitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_capacitor) on all integrated circuits.
2. You have unconnected op-amps in your OP-490.  The unconnected op-amps can pick up noise from the environment.  They may also oscillate.

The noise produced by the unconnected op-amps will cause interference on the power supply lines - you'll see noise on the outputs of all the ICs.

You need to properly connect all unused op-amps in the OP-490.  [This document from Texas Instruments goes into some detail about how and why.](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sboa204)

These two diagrams from the TI document summarise what you need to do:

[image]

[image]

Once you take care of that, you need to add decoupling capacitors from all IC power pins to ground.  Check the datasheets for recommended values.  If the datasheets don't specify a value, use 100nF capacitors.  Place them as close as possible to the power pins, and use short connections to power and ground.

Comment: pls see edit.. it's actually complete 2 channel with all ports connected. What is the source of the noise now?

Comment: Your new diagram still doesn't show decoupling capacitors.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing how your actual circuit is built, it is going to be nearly impossible to help you to track down the origin of the noise you are observing. Is it wired up on a breadboard? Are you using a generic PCB? Is it a custom PCB with proper grounding and shielding (ideally)? Is the attachment of your Ag/AgCl electrodes to the skin adequate?

As @JRE has clearly pointed out, you must use decoupling capacitors and *disable* all unused OPAMPS from your circuit. Additionally, you need to keep the test leads as short as possible and more importantly, your power supply MUST be electrically isolated. This is a crucial step when designing medical equipment for safety reasons. Please read [this](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/ecg-front-end-design-simplified.html) article from Analog on ECG front-end design. Ideally, you should be using batteries. Interestingly, batteries can be noisy too.

Inspecting your circuit, I can see that you are using high-value resistors (10 MOhms), which have higher thermal noise.

Even if you simulate your circuit with LTspice, you will not be able to fully simulate noise under real-life conditions.

As a matter of fact, noise reduction in Electrocardiography (ECG), Electroencephalography (EEG) and Electromyography (EMG) is not a trivial task. You can easily pursue a whole PhD in Noise Reduction Techniques for Medical Equipment.

Comment: please see edited post. it's from the Brainmaster 2E.

Answer (score 1):

Your traced circuit is incomplete. The inamp front end gain is only 450 and the 8-bit ADC in the HC711 has a resolution of ~12mV at best, which is inadequate for measuring EEG AFAIUI (10~100uV peak for the entire signal).

So probably some gain (100 as an order of magnitude) in the quad op-amp. There's some parts to maintain the input CM voltages within inamp input range with a human body as the source. Also something to bias the output so that the MCU ADC input range is respected.

Anyway, if you have not broken something in the mucking about, then it's probably still working as well as it ever did.

The whole thing looks very much like a crude prototype that they built a small quantity of. So many fixes, "klingons", ECOs whatever you want to call them.

Maybe you can find a used one in a garage sale, Craig's List or on eBay if you really want to replace it.

Comment: The gain in the 2e spec is 20,000. why did you mention "100 as an order of magnitude" for the quad op490. did you mean multiply 450x100 = 45000 gain?  lets compute, take 100microvolt or 0.100millivolt x 20000gain = 2000millivolt. or 2 volts. and 2V/12mv for hc11= 166 resolution? why not adequate for the ADC? how do you add the gain of each op-amp?  multiply them?  i didnt trace the hc11 clock, serial port or transistor regulator but the opamp trace is complete and correct.

Comment: Yes, to the gain. I am looking at your schematic, not at the spec. You multiply the gains of cascaded amplifiers. So if the OP490 gain is 50 that's *exactly* what I said is expected, but it is not reflected in your schematic as of this moment, that I can see.

Comment: In the top AD620 for channel 1, the -IN A and +IN A of 
AD620 already compensate for the Active and Ref input of the electrodes. But why does its output goes to -IN A of OP490 via a 200k resistor. And then the Out A and -In A of OP490 connected with a 836RCN. And then both the electrodes of Active & Ref going to +IN A of the OP490? What does it exactly do? Can you please run that portion at Spice. Thanks.